# Simple calculator in C using strncpy

Tags: c, math, strncpy

Take a look at the script. It calculates telop and prints the answer. As you can see it can only calculate plus (+) now. I have never done any C coding and so I don't know how to make it calculate multiplication (X or *), minus (-) and division (: or /) aswell.

So basically I was hoping if someone could tell me how to include multiplication, minus and division.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int total = 0;
void telop(char*s) {
char sum[1024];

if (s[0]==0) return;
if (s[0]=='+')

{
      strncpy(sum, &s[1],1);
      total += atoi(sum);
}
    telop(&s[2]);
}

int main()

{
    telop("+1+2+3");
    printf("%d", total);
}
```

Comment: this is not a script. it is source code for a compiled language.

Comment: Is this homework? Please try to investigate by yourself and ask a precise question on the difficulties you encounter.

Comment: HINT:A small calculator is a lot easier to program if it takes Polish notation input.

Comment: there is no easy way to add operation with different prorities - google for `Recursive Descent parsing`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you change the "+" in "-" then it calculates, you could also use this with "/" or "*"

```
void telop (char*s){
    char som[1024];
    if(s[0]==0) return;

    if(s[0]=='+')
    {   strncpy (som, &s[1],1);
        total += atoi(som); }
    if(s[0]=='-')
    {   strncpy (som, &s[1],1);
        total -= atoi(som); }
    if(s[0]=='/')
    {   strncpy (som, &s[1],1);
        total /= atoi(som); }
    if(s[0]=='*')
    {   strncpy (som, &s[1],1);
        total *= atoi(som); }



    telop(&s[2]);
}
```